# matching multiple patterns multiple times a record with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to efficiently match multiple patterns at a time, which in principle works very well:

```
echo abcdef | awk \
'/abc/ {print "match abc"}
 /def/ {print "match def"}'
```

Additionally I want to match all occurrences in the record:

```
echo abcabc | awk \
'function findall(str, re) {
    while(match(str, re)) {
        print "match", re;
        str = substr(str, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
{
    findall($0, "abc");
}'
```

Now to extend the above sample to match multiple patterns I would end up with a series of findall invokations:

```
findall($0, "abc");
...
findall($0, "def");
```

The problem is that with *many different patterns (>100)* this approach doesn't perform nearly as well as the first sample. Which makes sense, since the pattern do not end up in the same automaton I guess.

Is there a way to speed up things a little? e.g. providing "match" with multiple patterns. I guess I could concatenate the patterns (abc|def) but then I would loose the information which pattern exactly was the one that matched.

**Update:** Every single occurrence should be matched:

```
abcabc
123
abcxyz
```

as input data results in *2 matching records* (given the standard separator) but *4 matches in the whole data* if used with the patterns "abc" and "xyz".
The first sample in this post at least reports *3 matches*, but fails on detecting the multiple occurrences of "abc" in the first record

Comment: I want more information
1. what is desired if the patterns overlap? for example, when you try to match /abc|ca/ in "abcabc"?
2. are your patterns as simple as in the post (plain letter sequences)? w/o quantity operators, character ranges?

Answer (score 2):

how about do it in this way:

you put your patterns in a file, each pattern in a line, instead of in an awk function.

e.g.

```
kent$  cat p.txt
abc
def
foo
xxx
```

then you can load the file, and let awk do the matching job for you. at the end, print out only those patterns that matched your input string:

```
    echo inputString|awk 'NR==FNR{ps[$0]=0;next;}
{for(p in ps)if(match($0,p))ps[p]++;}
END{for(p in ps) if(ps[p]>0)print p" matched"}' p.txt -
```

of course, you could replace the "-" with input file if you need.

a small test:

```
kent$  echo "abcdefoobarblah"|awk 'NR==FNR{ps[$0]=0;next;}{for(p in ps)if(match($0,p))ps[p]++;}END{for(p in ps) if(ps[p]>0)print p" matched"}' p.txt -
def matched
foo matched
abc matched
```

so, the pattern "xxx" was not matched. only def,foo,abc were printed out.

**Note** that the script could be optimized and made shorter. for example, save the END{} block, do the print in the first for loop.  however, it shows you my idea how to do with it.

**EDIT for OP's comment**

Joe, I didn't see the requirement of matching times in your question. however it is not difficult to achieve. See the test below with your example text:

```
kent$  echo "abcabcabcdefoobarblah"|
awk 'NR==FNR{ps[$0]=0;next;}
{for(p in ps){t=$0;ps[p]=gsub(p,"",t);}}
END{for(p in ps) if(ps[p]>0)print p" matched "ps[p]" time(s)"}' p.txt -
```

**output:**

```
def matched 1 time(s)
foo matched 1 time(s)
abc matched 3 time(s)
```

Comment: This does not match every occurrence of the patterns within each record. `echo "abcabcabcdefoobarblah"|awk 'NR==FNR{ps[$0]=0;next;}{for(p in ps)if(match($0,p))ps[p]++;}END{for(p in ps) if(ps[p]>0)print p" matched "ps[p]" time(s)"}' p.txt -` states that "abc" was found once, although it appears 3 times in the record. Using "findall" in your code again brings us back to our initial problem :/

Comment: The update provides the expected result, but suffers from the very same lack of performance as the "findall" adaptation